# django restframework : url filter with two model field

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I want to design a url like :

```
url(r'^theaters/(?P<area>.+)/(?P<title>.+)/$', TheaterAreaList.as_view(), name='theater-area'),
```

and then I can go to the link like:

`http://127.0.0.1:8000/theaters/north/moviename`

But the `title` and `area` are in different models with manytomany relationship :

models.py

```
class Movie(models.Model):
    link = models.URLField()
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)

class MovieTheater(models.Model):
    movietheater = models.ManyToManyField(Movie,null=True,blank=True,through="MovieShowtime")
    movie_theater = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)     
    city = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)     #east west north south

class MovieShowtime(models.Model):
    theater = models.ForeignKey( MovieTheater, null=True,blank=True,related_name = 'theater' )
    movie = models.ForeignKey( Movie, null=True,blank=True,related_name = 'movie' )
    time = models.TextField(null=True,blank=True)
```

my views.py has error  `QuerySet' object has no attribute 'movietheater_set'`
views.py:

```
class TheaterAreaList(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = TheaterSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):

        area = self.kwargs['city']
        title = self.kwargs['title']
        return MovieTheater.objects.filter(city=area).movietheater_set.filter(title=title)
```

Please teach me how to query with two models ,Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `_set` would work only for objects, and not filtered querysets.

Try this:

```
MovieTheater.objects.filter(city=area, movietheater__movie__title=title)
```

Here is the [relevant documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships)

Comment: Thanks. ````MovieTheater.objects.filter(city=area, movietheater__title=title)```` works well